# Parsing rules file, c# regex not seeing pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I have taken my regex from python and try to make work in c#, while i get no errors, it does not display any output and during debug, i do not see the output varible get populated with any data, here is snippet:

```
StringWriter strwriter = new StringWriter();
rule = sr.ReadLine();
do
{                    
    Regex action = new Regex(@"^#\w+(?<action>(alert)\\s+(tcp|udp)\\s+(.*?)\\('*}))");
    Regex message = new Regex("(?<msg>[\\s(]*\\((.*)\\)[^)]*$)", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
    Regex content = new Regex("(?<content>[\\s(]*\\((.*)\\)[^)]*$)", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
    Match result = action.Match(rule); 
    //String repl = Regex.Replace(rule, "[\\;]", ",");
    //Match mat = action.Match(repl);
    Console.WriteLine(result.Groups["action"].Value);
    //writer.WriteLine(result.Groups["action"].Value + "," + result.Groups["msg"].Value + "," + result.Groups["content"].Value + "," + result.Groups["flow"].Value + "," + result.Groups["ct"].Value + "," + result.Groups["pcre"].Value + "," + result.Groups["sid"].Value);
} while (rule != null);
```

result does not show anything, what have i missed, these are almost the same one that i have working in the python script.

Comment: To get help, try posting an example of a sample input string with the desired output

Comment: Could this be that you're not actually advancing in the loop? Your call to `sr.ReadLine` only happens **once**.

Comment: You should provide a sample of the text the regular expressions are used for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using string literals for the first regex, don't double escape!

```
^#\w+(?<action>(alert)\\s+(tcp|udp)\\s+(.*?)\\('*}))
                      ^            ^        ^
```

=>

```
^#\w+(?<action>(alert)\s+(tcp|udp)\s+(.*?)\('*}))
```

---

With the input, there were a couple of more things wrong with the regex and this one should bring you in the right direction:

```
^#\s*(?<action>alert\s+(?:tcp|udp)\s+(.*?)\([^)]*\))
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/gO9zY9)

If you don't want the part within parentheses, you can omit the last part:

```
^#\s*(?<action>alert\s+(?:tcp|udp)\s+(.*?)\()
```

Comment: That fixed the getting the regexs to be seen, but i still get a null output for the result, i have check the file, and that line is in there so it should pick it up and parse it, the new line shows                                              [code]                                                                            Regex action = new Regex(@"^#\w+(?<action>(alert)\s+(tcp|udp)\s+(.*?)\('*})");[code]

Comment: the line is : [code:]   rule "# alert tcp $HOME_NET 2589 -> $EXTERNAL_NET any (msg:\"MALWARE-BACKDOOR - Dagger_1.4.0\"; flow:to_client,established; content:\"2|00 00 00 06 00 00 00|Drives|24 00|\"; depth:16; metadata:ruleset community; classtype:misc-activity; sid:105; rev:14;); [code]

Comment: i will as soon as i can access after work, we block all those sites.

Comment: @user2506189 There were a couple of things wrong with it. I changed it and it's now like [this](http://regex101.com/r/cI0qF1). Could you confirm whether this is what you were looking for?

Comment: it almost did, i changed a few to get just what i wanted, i basically only wanted the first part, all others work:                      [bold] ^#\s*(?<action>alert\s+(?:tcp|udp)\s+(.*?)*\()                   Thank You

Comment: @user2506189 Okay then. I'll be adding my previous regex to my answer. Fell free to mark it as accepted so your question is 'marked' as resolved.